# How can I write a test that involves accessing the EmailMessage.ActivityId field?

Tags: unit-test, tasks, emailmessage

I have some code that involves the following SOQL query:

```
EmailMessage emailMessage = [SELECT Id FROM EmailMessage WHERE ActivityId =: task.Id];
```

In order to write a test for this code, the test setup will need to insert an EmailMessage that is linked to a Task. However, the EmailMessage ActivityId field is read-only, so I can't manually specify the value. What should I do? How can I write a test that involves an EmailMessage and a Task being linked together?

EDIT: Here's the full function I'm trying to test:

```
public string getAttachmentIds(Task task) {
    string cvString = '';

    // Get the EmailMessage associated with the Task
    EmailMessage emailMessage = [SELECT Id FROM EmailMessage WHERE ActivityId =: task.Id];

    // Get all ContentDocumentLinks that point to our EmailMessage
    List<ContentDocumentLink> contentDocumentLinks = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId =: emailMessage.Id];

    // Get the IDs of all ContentDocuments related to our ContentDocumentLinks
    List<Id> contentDocumentIds = new List<Id>();
    for (ContentDocumentLink link : contentDocumentLinks) {
        contentDocumentIds.Add(link.ContentDocumentId);
    }

    // Get all ContentVersions related to our ContentDocuments
    List<ContentVersion> contentVersions = [SELECT Id FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId IN: contentDocumentIds];

    // Add each Content Version Id to a comma separated list
    for (ContentVersion contentVersion : contentVersions) {
        cvString += contentVersion.Id + ',';
    }
    return cvString = cvString.RemoveEnd(',');
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you can't specify the activityId? "ActivityId can only be specified for emails on cases. It’s auto-created for other entities." https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm

Comment: worth learning how to do dependency injection so you can mock queries (via a selector class) without worrying about how to create the sobjects

Comment: @CommonCoreTawan: Yes, when I try to instantiate an EmailMessage with my own values it gives me an error saying that the field is read only.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hack. If you are running a test (as in, the code is called by a test class), then don't filter by activityId

```
EmailMessage emailMessage;

if(Test.isRunningTest()){
    emailMessage = [SELECT Id FROM EmailMessage LIMIT 1];
}
else{
    emailMessage = [SELECT Id FROM EmailMessage WHERE ActivityId =: task.Id];
}
```

This would work because in your test class, presumably, you are only creating 1 EmailMessage object, so the first query would retrieve that.

If you are not in a test, then use the task Id.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going with this solution.